# Slow down trackpad scroll speed

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

Ubuntu 21.04 on Dell XPS 13 9370

The trackpad scrolling gesture is too fast, but I can't seem to find a way to slow it down in the system settings. I've read about tweaking things with xinput but it's a Wayland device so I don't think that's an option so not really sure what to try next.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem by disabling Wayland

## Disable altogether

`sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

and uncomment this line

`WaylandEnable=false`

## Disable for a user

On the GDM login screen you can select on the bottom-right "Ubuntu on X11" instead of default "Ubuntu"

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu Linux on an Amazon Workspace and have the same issue. Since the trackpad and mouse are seen as the same device it's a bit difficult to deal with.

For mouse scrolling you can try imwheel which worked really well for mouse but made no impact on the trackpad scrolling.

For trackpad I would say you could look at seeing if Dell now offers a separate app for trackpad settings (since it's been some time and they normally do offer that for windows) but for VMs I had to change the settings on my local windows machine to its slowest setting, and only then did it slow down the scrolling a bit (still very fast but doesn't jump miles at a time anymore).